# Why can't find RdKafka?

Tags: php, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I have a dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.9-fpm
...............................
RUN apt-get install librdkafka-dev -y
RUN pecl install rdkafka \
    && docker-php-ext-enable rdkafka
```

After **docker-compose build and up -d**, exec container php, make php -m and I saw **rdkafka** in module list.

Similary in composer.json added and installed:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "ext-rdkafka": "*",
```

In this project I used php framework **Lumen**.
**The question:** when I'm trying in any class to put **$conf = new RdKafka\Conf();** - every time I got an error: **Undefined class 'Conf'**

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install ext-rdkafka.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? I am running `docker-php-ext-install rdkafka` and am still getting `error: /usr/src/php/ext/rdkafka does not exist`

Comment: @Prof you need to install the `librdkafka`. Please check the Readme file https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka